# Teams Chat Message with File Attachment After Uploading Large File to OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I used the following tutorial, [Upload large files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp), to successfully upload a file to a user's OneDrive.  The response of the UploadAsync operation is a DriveItem.

From there I used [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp), **Example 4:  Send a message with file attachment in it**, to send a chat message in Teams where I used the information from the newly created DriveItem to send the message into the chat as follows:

```
    string contentUrl = Combine(myDrive.WebUrl, driveItem.Name);
    string eTag = driveItem.ETag.Split('{', '}')[1];
    
    var requestBody = new ChatMessage
    {
        Subject = null,
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = string.Format("Here is my file <attachment id=\"{0}\"></attachment>", eTag),
        },
        Attachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>
        {
            new ChatMessageAttachment
            {
                Id = eTag,
                ContentType = "reference",
                ContentUrl = contentUrl,
                Name = driveItem.Name,
                TeamsAppId = "{my-app-id}"
            },
        },
    };
    
    Task<ChatMessage> postTask =  graphClient.Chats[chatId].Messages.PostAsync(requestBody);
    postTask.Wait();
```

So the file is successfully saved to OneDrive, and the chatMessage comes through with the attachment link.  *The issue I'm having is that while I can click the file and launch it into Teams, the browser, or download it, the other user in the 1:1 chat receives an error message when trying to access the file in any way.*

[Chat Message with File Attachment Successfully Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDMFw.png)
[Error Message when User within my organization tries to access this in 1:1 chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ham3.png)

I'm thinking is has something to do with the **Sharing** property of the file in OneDrive, but I'm unsure as to how to programmatically modify the property from **Private** to **Sharing**.  I see the Microsoft.Graph.Models.Shared property of the DriveItem, but I'm not seeing how to modify this property successfully.

[This property is what I'm thinking I need to address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBAf6.png)

I'm using the "OnBehalfOf" flow and instantiating the GraphServiceClient using an authorization token from Teams JS microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken.

```
private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetOnBehalfOfClient(string authToken){
    
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    
    var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    };
    
     var accessTokenProvider = new OnBehalfOfCredential(
        ExchangeTenantId, ExchangeAppId, ExchangeSecret, authToken, options);
        
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(accessTokenProvider, scopes);  
    
    return graphClient;
}
```

Can anyone offer some insight as to what is occurring in my scenario?  Why am I, the teams user initiating the file upload and chat message, able to download the file attachment in the chat message, but the other user in my organization receives the permissions error shown above?

Any ideas as to how to alter this permissions programmatically so I can share this newly created DriveItem with the other user?

I appreciate any help here.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share the error details that you are facing here?

Comment: I don't receive a runtime error with my code, the other user is just unable to access the file that I've shared within the Team's chat.  See image I've linked "Error Message when User within my organization tries to access this in 1:1 chat".

Comment: By default, when you upload a file to OneDrive, only the owner has access to it. To enable other users to download the file, you need to set the appropriate permissions. You can use the Graph APIs to update the permissions for the file. Refer to the
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online
for more details on how to manage permissions for files.

Comment: I have tried using var result = await graphClient.Drives["drive_id"].Items["drive_item_id"].CreateLink.PostAsync(linkRequestBody) to change the item to shared, but then I can't use the created sharing link in the ChatMessageAttachment request because that link doesn't have a proper file name with extension, and it throws a runtime error when the ContentUrl property doesn't have an name/extension matching the Name property.  Do you have an example to Send a message with a file attachment after the drive item has been shared?  I don't see this in the documentation.  Thanks.

Comment: Any follow up here?  How do I programmatically share a newly created DriveItem then use it in a ChatMessageAttachment request in Chat Messages PostAsync?